# Hibernate saving duplicate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a Many-To-One relationship between two table in my database User table & Country table. The model classes are:

```
@Entity (name = "user")
 public class User {

      @Id @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
      private int userId;
      private String username;
      private String password;

      @ManyToOne (cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
      @JoinColumn (name = "countryId")
      private Country country;

     //Getter & Setter
 }


  @Entity (name = "country")
  public class Country {

      @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
      private int countryId;
      private String countryName;
      //Getter & Setter
 }
```

The problem I am having is when I save a new User object it also saves a new country record even when that country already exist in the database. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

You can try changing the *cascade type* in the `@ManyToOne` relationship:

```
@ManyToOne (cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
@JoinColumn (name = "countryId")
private Country country;
```

When using `CascadeType.ALL`, it also includes, `CascadeType.PERSIST`, in which case, the persist operation is cascaded to *Country* whenever your persist *User*.

Comment: This create a new problem. It's not saving the object now

Comment: @MarioDennis. Can you try removing the cascade completely.

Comment: When I remove it I get: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Data was not saved: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.kyrogaming.models.Country

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand `Country` table is like dictionary and in most cases you should't save it every time you save an entity. Why do you need to save it by cascade?

If you really have to update `Country` why wouldn't it be done before saving `User` instance?

Using `CascadeType.ALL` is not really good because you will loose `Country` when you delete `User`.